# Fitting data to left skewed gamma distribution

Tags: fitting, distributions

How can I fit the following two set of data to a left skewed gamma function, which I what I think should fit the data best?:

data 1 is here: https://pastebin.com/X2HTjTP7
data 2 is here: https://pastebin.com/8Rh4BHDT

Is there any other suggestion of what would be the best distribution or equation to fit the data?

EDIT: I tried using `FindDistributionParameters[data2,GammaDistribution[Alpha,[Beta]]]` but I get a message saying "FindDistributionParameters::ntsprt: One or more data points are not in support of the process or distribution GammaDistribution[[Alpha],[Beta]]."

A picture of how data 1 looks is here:

[image: data 1]

A picture of how data 2 looks is here:

[image: data 2]

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: Have you already seen `FindDistributionParameters[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I get the following "the value of the GammaDistribution is not a recognized distribution" using `FindDistributionParameters[data2, GammaDistribution]`. Additionally, I am not sure how to put it to be left skewed Gamma distribution

Comment: Might I suggest editing your question to include that attempt and the errors you got? It might be useful for diagnostics.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you! I have edited the question to include that.

Comment: I apologize for not immediately noticing earlier, but it seems you have some points that go below the $x$-axis (i.e. they have negative $y$ coordinates). Would  `FindDistributionParameters[]` work if you remove them temporarily?

Comment: Your data has complex numbers. Distributions only handle real data.

Comment: @BobHanlon even removing those data and leaving only the real data does not seem to work for `FindDistributionParameters[]`. Does it work for you?. I was not able to make it work with the real data.

Comment: You have the completely wrong idea.  If you had random samples from a "skewed gamma" distribution, then `FindDistributionParameters` would be appropriate.  But what you have is a curve that has a shape like a reverse gamma distribution and therefore you want to perform a regression with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @JimB the question is how to do the `NonlinearModelFit` using a reverse gamma distribution?. Could you post that as an answer please?. Thank you !

Comment: Didn’t I do that?

Comment: @JimB Yes! Sorry my website did not updated your answer.! Thank you for your help! I appreciate it

Comment: FYI.  The second dataset does not fit a gamma distribution curve as well especially where the peak is located (between 106 to 116 in horizontal units).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are fitting a curve that has a shape of a known probability distribution and NOT fitting a probability distribution.  This is a regression.

After throwing out the complex numbers (as suggested by @BobHanlon) and throwing out the negative response values, one can use `NonlinearModelFit`.  Fitting the log of the curve is more numerically stable when using `NonlinearModelFit`.

```
xmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]] + 0.0001;
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 2]] = Log[data[[All, 2]]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data2, {logc - (xmax - x)/b + a Log[xmax - x], 
   b > 0 && a > 0}, {{a, 0.5}, {b, 2}, {logc, -11}}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 0.523033, b -> 2.03643, logc -> -11.2393} *)
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Yellow, Thickness[0.02]}}], 
 Plot[Exp[nlm[x]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], xmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Comment: I am using the data2 removing the negative values and also the complex numbers as you suggested and then I am putting exactly the code you posted but I do not get what you get. The data I am using to be precise is this: https://pastebin.com/qXMbF0FG . Is there something from the data I did not remove that needs to be removed?. Also, could you tell me if you don't mind why is there a need to use data2 and data? You are using only data2 (the one I have pasted here), correct? or both data at the same time?

Comment: I think I understand what you did. You only used `data` but then named it `data2`. That confused me a little bit but the code works!. Thanks JimB

Comment: JimB one more question: How can I find the area under the curve?. I am using: `area = NIntegrate[Exp[nlm[x]], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]` but it does not work.

Comment: Does the error message suggest what might be wrong?

Comment: I get the following: `NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (E^FittedModel[0.00701413 +3.23571*10^-7 Log[<<1>>]-<<2>>^2])[x] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{74.0202,148.342}}.`

Comment: I was able to solve it now JimB!It was something of a notation rather than something else. I appreciate your help.